# Manually update some DataGrid's elements

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, dependency-properties

I have this `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgTimeline" Focusable="False" GotFocus="dgTimeline_GotFocus">
```

So I add columns with a custom class called `TimelineControl` and bind its `Minutes` properties with `Time%`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
    FrameworkElementFactory fef = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TimelineControl));
    Binding bTemp = new Binding("Time" + i);
    bTemp.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    fef.SetValue(TimelineControl.MinutesProperty, bTemp);
    DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
    dt.VisualTree = fef;
    dgTempCol.CellTemplate = dt;

    dgTimeline.Columns.Add(dgTempCol);
}
```

Here is `TimelineControl`:

```
public static DependencyProperty MinutesProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Minutes", typeof(string), typeof(TimelineControl),
new PropertyMetadata(OnMinutesChanged));

public string Minutes
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(MinutesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MinutesProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnMinutesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("foo bar");
}
```

Latter on I add some rows with:

```
TimeScale temp;
temp = this.addEvent(temp, 23);
temp = this.addEvent(temp, 24);
temp = this.addEvent(temp, 25);
temp = this.addEvent(temp, 26);

dgTimeline.Items.Add(temp);

private TimeScale addEvent(TimeScale temp, int time)
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = temp.GetType().GetProperty("Time" + (time / 60));

    if (propertyInfo.GetValue(temp, null) != null)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.GetValue(temp, null).ToString().IndexOf((time % 60).ToString()) == -1)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(temp, Convert.ChangeType(propertyInfo.GetValue(temp, null) +
                "," + (time % 60), propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(temp, Convert.ChangeType(time % 60, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Everything works fine so far, the `OnMinutesChanged` is triggered just fine and the UI is updated. The problem is that when I try to update something that is on the `DataGrid` the `OnMinutesChanged` is not triggered and the UI is not updated.

My objective with `OnMinutesChanged` is to manually update the UI of the specific elements that were changed. If I call `dgTimeline.Items.Refresh()` then the whole grid is refreshed and everything works, the `OnMinutesChanged` is called. The problem is that this grid is updated every second, so call `dgTimeline.Items.Refresh()` makes the application almost freeze because the number of elements is high (more than 500 easily). I just need to update 3 elements' UI per second, not all the 500, that's why I want to manually do it.

Am I doing the right thing? If yes, why `OnMinutesChanged` is not being called when I update the grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGrid` uses [binding groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.bindinggroupname.aspx) to validate the whole row and prevent an invalid state in the underlying object in case one of the properties is assigned an invalid value. This changes the default [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) of bindings within cells to `Explicit`, you can override this by explicitly setting it to `PropertyChanged` on your binding object.

Normally the update is invoked if the user finishes editing a row, you however never enter edit mode as you use `CellTemplate` and not `CellEditingTemplate`.

Comment: So if I set `bTemp.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;` the `OnMinutesChanged` will be triggered without calling `dgTimeline.Items.Refresh()`?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong: It should.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not doing so. Still only triggering `OnMinutesChanged` when calling `dgTimeline.Items.Refresh();`

Comment: @FredericoSchardong: Your code looks off, shouldn't you use [`fef.SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.setbinding.aspx) instead of `fef.SetValue`? Also i should note that `FrameworkElementFactory` is deprecated.

Comment: Using `fef.SetValue` has no difference. What should I attribute to `VisualTree` if not a `FrameworkElementFactory`? Sorry, I am new to C# and WPF

Comment: @FredericoSchardong: So you get the initial values either way but they don't bind back when changed? Regarding `FrameworkElementFactory` MSDN suggest using the [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) to parse a XAML string describing the template, not a fan of it myself.

Comment: They do bind, however, the `OnMinutesChanged` that is associated with one of the bind's property's change is not triggered

Comment: @FredericoSchardong: Is that supposed to mean that the value on the bound object changes as well if you edit it but the changed event just does not fire?

Comment: Actually I don't know if it is binding or not, I just believe so because there is no reason to not to bind, the only way I have to verify if it is binding or not is seeing if the interface changes or if the event is fired. Which comes to my main problem: I have to call `refresh()` to refresh the interface and fire the event. Without `refresh` none of them happens. I am starting to think that the binding only happens when the interface is refreshed, which sucks.

Comment: To test if it binds your property should have some initial value that is shown in the UI, also you can [check for binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).